# Extract substring according to regexp with sed or grep

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

In a (BSD) UNIX environment, I would like to capture a specific substring using a regular expression.

Assume that the `dmesg` command output would include the following line:

```
pass2: <Marvell Console 1.01> Removable Processor SCSI device
```

I would like to capture the text between the `<` and `>` characters, like

`dmesg | <sed command>`

should output:

```
Marvell Console 1.01
```

However, it should not output anything if the regex does not match. Many solutions including `sed -e 's/$regex/\1/` will output the whole input if no match is found, which is not what i want.

The corresponding regexp could be:
`regex="^pass2\: \<(.*)\>"`

How would i properly do a regex match using `sed` or `grep`? Note that the `grep -P` option is unavailable in my BSD UNIX distribution. The `sed -E` option is available, however.

Comment: It's possibly better to parse the output of `camcontrol devlist` than the output of `dmesg`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this,

```
sed -nE 's/^pass2:.*<(.*)>.*$/\1/p'
```

Or POSIXly (`-E` has not made it to the POSIX standard yet as of 2019):

```
sed -n 's/^pass2:.*<\(.*\)>.*$/\1/p'
```

Output:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'pass2: <Marvell Console 1.01> Removable Processor SCSI device' | sed -nE 's/^pass2:.*<(.*)>.*$/\1/p'
Marvell Console 1.01
```

This will only print the last occurrence of `<...>` for each line.

Comment: This works for me, with both the -n parameter and the /p suffix inside the regex. Full command i used: `dmesg | sed -nE 's/^pass2: <(.*)>.*$/\1/p`

Comment: Why not use `<([^>]+)>`? I.e. not-`>` one-or-more times

Comment: `sed` regex is per default non-greedy, so it's not necessary here. But it would work, too.

Answer (score 9):

How about `-o` under grep to just print the matching part? We still need to remove the `<>`, though, but `tr` works there.

```
dmesg |egrep -o "<([a-zA-Z\.0-9 ]+)>" |tr -d "<>"
Marvell Console 1.01
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried  below 3 methods by using sed, awk and python

**sed command**

```
echo "pass2: <Marvell Console 1.01> Removable Processor SCSI device" | sed "s/.*<//g"|sed "s/>.*//g"
```

output

```
Marvell Console 1.01
```

**awk command**

```
echo "pass2: <Marvell Console 1.01> Removable Processor SCSI device" | awk -F "[<>]" '{print $2}'
```

output

```
Marvell Console 1.01
```

**python**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
h=[]
k=open('l.txt','r')
l=k.readlines()
for i in l:
    o=i.split(' ')
    for i in o[1:4]:
        h.append(i)
print (" ".join(h)).replace('>','').replace('<','')
```

**output**

```
Marvell Console 1.01
```

Comment: I was thinking the `awk` approach too. Should you constrain your print to lines beginning with "pass2:"? The OP didn't provide sufficient detail, but I can imagine that a naive pattern match would not be _quite_ what was wanted.

Comment: Python can read from standard in, though perl specializes in this kind of text processing if you’re moving into higher level scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract substring with below `grep -o -e` command:

```
cat some.log | grep "lineWithThisText" | grep -o -e 'SomeSequence1[0-9]*[A-Z]*SomeSequence2'
```

For some reason `*` works rather than `+` for 1 or many match in this grep regex match command.

Read grep manual with the following command:

```
man grep
```

Read about options `-o` and `-e`.

I use this at work to extract tons of data from several log lines.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. The reason that `+` doesn't seem to work is that by default, `grep` interprets the regular expression as _basic regular expression_, which doesn't include the `+`. You will have to use the `-E` option in order to enable them (at least on GNU `grep`), or use `egrep` instead.